# Uploading and serving media files from google drive on django

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I'm working on an app in django that allows users to upload documents to google drive and share them with friends. The problem is I want to restrict the shared documents to view only (no download option). How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You can insert/upload files using the Drive API and set the "restricted" label to prevent downloading of the file. You would then set the appropriate permissions to this file to allow anyone or a specified set of users to access the file.

Download restrictions may or may not apply for files that are converted to one of the Google Apps formats because the option to prevent downloading seems unavailable for these files through the Google Drive UI. You would have to test this yourself.